# What are the legal names for infix operators?

Tags: ocaml, infix-notation, infix-operator

There seem to be a number of symbols that can act as infix operators; e.g.

- ints: `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, `(/)`, `mod`
- floats: `(+.)`, `(-.)`, `(*.)`, `(/.)`
- comparison: `(=)`, `(<>)`, `(<)`, `(<=)`, `(>)`, `(>=)`
- functions: `(|>)`, `(<<)`, `(>>)`
- monads: `(>>=)`, `(>>|)`
- lists: `(::)`, `(@)`
- misc: `(^)`, `(^/)`, `(^:)`

What determines whether a function can act as an infix operator or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's determined by the first symbol of the operator. From [the manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#infix-symbol):

```
infix-symbol    ::= (= ∣  < ∣  > ∣  @ ∣  ^ ∣  | ∣  & ∣  + ∣  - ∣  * ∣  / ∣  $ ∣  %) { operator-char }  
    ∣    # { operator-char }+  

prefix-symbol   ::= ! { operator-char }  
    ∣    (? ∣  ~) { operator-char }+  

operator-char   ::= ! ∣  $ ∣  % ∣  & ∣  * ∣  + ∣  - ∣  . ∣  / ∣  : ∣  < ∣  = ∣  > ∣  ? ∣  @ ∣  ^ ∣  | ∣  ~
```

So, for example, a custom operator defined like this:

```
let (@?) a b = ...
```

Would be considered an infix operator since it starts with `@`, while

```
let (?@) a b = ...
```

is a prefix operator because it starts with `?`.

There are some additions and exceptions to this, however, described [in the manual here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec152):

- `mod`, `land`, `lor`, `lxor`, `lsl`, `lsr` and `asr` are keywords treated as infix operators (e.g. `2 mod 4`).
- `-` and `-.` can be interpreted as either infix or prefix operators. When prefix thay are translated to `~-` and `~-.` respectively.
- `&&` and `||` are also treated specially, for reasons. See the comments by @octachron below for a bit more of an explanation.

Lastly, you might also want to consider precedence and associativity, which is listed in the table near the top, [before the first section here](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html)

Comment: Sweet, just what I was looking for. As a small follow-up question, is there somewhere in the manual where operators like `(mod)` are special-cased?

Comment: I think it might be special-cased just by being a keyword. I'm not sure whether the manual says explicitly that these keywords are treated as infix operators though.

Comment: These special cases are described in the manual too : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec152 .

Comment: @octachron Ah, thanks, that's a much better starting point for this. Do you know in which way `&&` and `||` are handled specially, as mentioned there?

Comment: `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting (because they are defined as external primitives), which is not the case for normal infix operators. This leads to some strange behavior if they are redefined for instance `let (&&) = (&&)` results in a non-shortcircuiting  `(&&)`. Similarly, redefining `~-` results in strange behaviors when using the unary short-hand `-`.

Comment: @octachron Hmm, what do you mean by "external primitives"? It doesn't seem to be that they're defined as e.g. `external ( && ) : ... = "%sequand"`, since [other infix operators](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/pervasives.ml#L54) are defined similarly.

Comment: [`let ( @ ) = ( @ )`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/pervasives.ml#L138) and [`let ( ^ ) = ( ^ )`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/pervasives.ml#L138) seems to be more like what you're talking about.

Comment: Other infix operators are also defined as compiler primitives indeed, but they share a similar semantic in term of execution as non-primitive operators, whereas `%sequand` and `%sequor%`  have distinct semantics in term of evaluation. For instance,  `false && (effect ())` never computes `effect()`but rebinding `let (&&) = (&&)` hides the compiler primitive behind a normal function that evaluates its two arguments first and thus computes `effect ()` .

Comment: Ah, I see, the intricacies of side-effects strike again! Make total sense though. Thanks for explaining!